# Show a Image on Xamarin from byte[]

Tags: c#, image, xamarin, stream, arrays

I saw many examples here and I am trying to adapt to my code! But, when the image appears, it comes blank... 
I just want to show the image after the button click. Is not to save on the smartphone.

The .cs code:

```
ApiCall apiCallFoto = new ApiCall();
ImageSource imagem = null;

btnFoto.Clicked += async (sender, e) =>
{
    await apiCallFoto.GetFoto<byte[]>("Nomes", "Foto", envolvID).ContinueWith(t =>
    {
        //Aqui verificamos se houve problema ne requisição
        if (t.IsFaulted)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(t.Exception.Message);
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
            {
                   DisplayAlert("Falha", "Ocorreu um erro na Requisição :(", "Ok");
            });
         }
         //Aqui verificamos se a requisição foi cancelada por algum Motivo
       else if (t.IsCanceled)
       {
             Debug.WriteLine("Requisição cancelada");

             Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
             {
                   DisplayAlert("Cancela", "Requisição Cancelada :O", "Ok");
             });
        }

        //Caso a requisição ocorra sem problemas, cairemos aqui
        else
        {
            //Se Chegarmos aqui, está tudo ok, agora itemos tratar nossa Lista
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
            {
                 byte[] fotoBytes = t.Result;
                 // Image image = new Image();
                        imagem = ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(fotoBytes));

                  Navigation.PushAsync(new FotoEnvolvido(imagem));

            });

          }
     });
  };
```

The FotoEnvolvido.cs :

```
public partial class FotoEnvolvido : ContentPage
{
    private ImageSource imagem;

    public FotoEnvolvido(ImageSource imagem)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.imagem = imagem;
        BindingContext = imagem;

    }
}
```

The FotoEnvolvido.xaml :

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Image Source="{Binding imagem}" x:Name="fotoperfil"/>

</Grid>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your BindingContext needs to be `this` or you have to bind to `.`

```
public partial class FotoEnvolvido : ContentPage
{
    public ImageSource Imagem {get; set; }

    public FotoEnvolvido(ImageSource imagem)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Imagem = imagem;
        BindingContext = this;
    }
}

<Image Source="{Binding Imagem}" x:Name="fotoperfil"/>
```

or

```
public partial class FotoEnvolvido : ContentPage
{
    public FotoEnvolvido(ImageSource imagem)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = imagem;
    }
}

<Image Source="{Binding}" x:Name="fotoperfil"/>
```